# I can't use assets/links from another server

Tags: html, server, apache2

I'm migrating a website from GoDaddy to my own Apache server. If I even use a link that's outside of the Apache server, it immediately goes to the server's 404 page. I'm not sure why, but in everything I've checked, outside links work.  If you need more information, please comment that. You can prove this to yourself by opening [this link](http://la01.cianormond.com) and pressing the "Head back to main site" button. Here's the button's code: `<a href="domain.com"><button>Head back to the main site</button></a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I have figured out the answer. All I needed to do was add the `http://` to the link and now everything works.